# Is there a better way to do this if condition

Tags: php

I have this if statement

```
 if (!(@$donnees['mode']['delete'] === true || @$donnees['mode']['display'] === true)){
     //doSomething only if mode is not delete nor display 
 }
```

i used `@` to not get the notice when mode is not set.
because if i use isset instead it would be even uglier :

```
$cond_delete = isset($donnees['mode']['delete']) && $donnees['mode']['delete'] === true;
$cond_display = isset($donnees['mode']['display ']) && $donnees['mode']['display '] === true;

if (!($cond_delete || $cond_display)){
   //doSomething only if mode is not delete nor display 
}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: try array_key_exists() if you want to check that.

Comment: I prefer your second option. You call it ugly, I call it readable.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might be a good choice although it creates a couple of single use variables.

```
/*Either set values if setting available, or set false*/
$cond_delete = isset($donnees['mode']['delete'])? $donnees['mode']['delete']: false;
$cond_display = isset($donnees['mode']['display '])? $donnees['mode']['display ']: false;


/*Where either mode is set do something*/
if (!($cond_delete || $cond_display)){
 //doSomething only if mode is not delete nor display 
}
```

Comment: edited it to add this if (!($cond_delete || $cond_display)) instead of if ($cond_delete || $cond_display)

Answer (score 1):

If `$donnees[ 'mode' ][ 'delete' ]` / `$donnees[ 'mode' ][ 'display' ]` will only ever be A) set to `true`, or else B) set to `false` or something that would be considered `false` [when converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) -- e.g. undefined, `NULL`, 0, "0", empty string -- then you can omit the `=== true` and just let them evaluate to `true` or `false`.  E.g.:

```
if ( ! (

  @$donnees[ 'mode' ][ 'delete' ] ||

  @$donnees[ 'mode' ][ 'display' ]

) ) {

   // doSomething only if mode is not delete nor display 

}
// if
```

What other elements may `$donnees[ 'mode' ]` contain?

Unless you're just learning to program and don't know what you're doing yet, then notices (`E_NOTICE`) are just a nuisance and I'd disable them if possible.  With notices disabled, if you want to know if an array element actually exists, then you can use `array_key_exists()` or `isset()`, depending exactly what you're trying to find out.  If you just want to access the variable / array element and have it evaluate to `NULL` if it's undefined (which will evaluate to `false` when converting to boolean, as in an `if` / `else` expression), then you don't need to bloat your code with unnecessary tests that add no value.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($donnees['mode']['delete'], $donnees['mode']['display']) AND ($donnees['mode']['delete'] === true || $donnees['mode']['display'] === true)){
  //doSomething only if mode is not delete nor display
}
```